# Сглаживание пользовательского курсора

Tags: flash

Сделал пользовательский курсор

```
stage.addChild(movieClip_1);
movieClip_1.mouseEnabled = false;
movieClip_1.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fl_CustomMouseCursor);

function fl_CustomMouseCursor(event:Event)
{
    movieClip_1.x = stage.mouseX;
    movieClip_1.y = stage.mouseY;
}

Mouse.hide();
```

Но передвижение происходит рывками, а так же изображение не сглаживается.
Каким образом включить сглаживание (или глобально в проекте, или специально для курсора, на примере данного кода)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте:

```
// For smooth motion.
movieClip_1.transform.matrix3D = new Matrix3D();
// Или.
movieClip_1.rotation = 0.1;
```